# Pentaho to kill all running transformations if any one them fails

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have a wrapper job which runs 4 transformations in parallel. I want to kill all the four transformations if any one of the running transformation fails.

If it would have been a wrapper transformation there is a possibility of error handling through setting a condition `ExecutionNrErrors > 0`.

If I add an abort job step on all these transformations it will make the other transformations killed but with a green tick instead of a red tick.

How do we achieve this in Pentaho Jobs?

[image: Sample]

Comment: Can you explain why, please. The two behavior (1) `continue parallels path if one of them falls`, and (2) `abort is not an error and does not propagates` are choices that have been discussed at length and tested on numerous cases. On cases where a different behavior was required , we always found an alternative. But we need a use case.

Comment: Based on the failure of those transformations I will be triggering an error handling and alerting transformation which will notify different users groups. If one transformation fails and kills the rest with a green tick, my alerting mechanism wont take place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a solution like that:

[image]

It won't work, but even if no transformation fails. The rule in Pentaho Data Integrator is to start a transformation as soon as possible. So the Success or Failure step will start as soon as one of the transformation finishes.

You are warned of this facts, when you specify the transformations to run parallel.

If you want the transformations parallel, you have to define a lock mechanism yourself. You can also replace your main job by a transformation, in which every thing is parallel, and you have `Blocking step` to wait for all teh transformation to finish.